# Does bounded and closed equal compact for sets of Borel probability measures?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, probability-distributions

Equip the space of Borel probability measures on a fixed closed subset X of the s-dimensional Euclidean space with the topology induced by weak convergence of probability measures. In this setting, does compact equal bounded and closed (with respect to the Prokhorov metric)? If not, is there a simple counterexample?

Comment: If I'm using the right definition, the Kantorovich (aka transportation or Wasserstein) metric doesn't even induce the weak topology: convergence in the metric is equivalent to weak convergence plus convergence of first moments.  So any sequence of measures that converges weakly but has unbounded first moments should give a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it was supposed to be the Prokhorov metric.

Comment: You mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric) Prokhorov metric?  It's a bounded metric, so the "bounded" part is trivial, and certainly not every weakly closed set of probability measures is compact.  Or have I got the wrong definition again?

Comment: If $X$ is compact then the set of all Borel  probability measures is weakly compact (and also weakly sequentially compact). This is a simple version of Prokhorov's theorem (or, in functional analytic terms, Alaoglu's theorem, functional analysts call the weak topology weak* topology). Of course, closed subsets of compact sets are again compact.